# Recursive function with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a recursive function to fetch data from an external source, process it and make additional calls if necessary.

I need to pause before call this external source too many times in succession.

How do I ensure that I have all the results from my external resource before calling my "final" function?

```
function showAll(results) {
    console.log('All done, time for doing something else with results')
    console.log(results)
}

function checkName(person) {
    console.log('checking name of ' + person.name)
    if (person.name === 'Julie') return true 
}

function checkPersons(url) {
        // Do something here to get new data from an external source
    var data = {
        // 'goAgain': https://newUrl.com,
        'results': [
          {name: 'Bob', age: 21},
          {name: 'Frank', age: 15, go: 1},
          {name: 'Julie', age: 12}
        ]
    }

    var persons = data.results
    var results = []

    persons.forEach(function(person, i) {
        if (person.age >= 18) {
            console.log('do not need to check name of ' + person.name)
            results.push(person)
        } else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (checkName(person)) {
                    console.log('Julie is ' + person.name)
                    results.push(person)
                }
            }, 5000 * i)
        }        
    })

    if (data.goAgain) {
      // Go back and call the function again to get the 
      // next set of results from external source
      // checkPersons(goAgain)
      console.log('Calling the function again to get more results if necessary')
    } else {
      // But, checkName is still running because of setTimeout
      // so results doesn't yet have everything we need
      showAll(results)
    }
}

checkPersons('https://someurl.com')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nicholasduffy/28Lpsgbj/3/

```
do not need to check name of Bob
// No, clearly not all done because we haven't checked Frank or Julie yet   
(index):27 All done, time for doing something else with results
// Just Bob
(index):28 [Object]
(index):32 checking name of Frank
(index):32 checking name of Julie
(index):57 Julie is Julie
// Now I really want results
```

Comment: Are you expecting the server to send down some sort of done signal?

Comment: I'm expecting to check for the existence of data.goAgain. If it's there, I know I'm going to need to make at least one more call. If it's not there, I know that this was my last call.

Comment: Cool. So, if you're depending on the external data producer to let you know when your have all the data you need, then it'll have to be the one to send that data down. Are you wondering how to set the `data.goAgain` property? :)

Comment: or are you asking "what goes here?" for `// Do something here to get new data from an external source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle waiting for asynchronous actions.  A good way to do that is using `Promises`.  Also, even if you don't need to wait for a `setTimeout`, it's a good idea to handle *all* of them like they could be.  That makes your flow much easier to maintain:

```
var promises = persons.map(function(person, i) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (person.age >= 18) {
            console.log('do not need to check name of ' + person.name)
            results.push(person);
            return resolve();
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (checkName(person)) {
                console.log('Julie is ' + person.name)
                results.push(person);
            }
            resolve();
        }, 5000 * i)
    });
})

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(function() {
        if (data.goAgain) {
            // Go back and call the function again to get the 
            // next set of results from external source
            // checkPersons(goAgain)
            console.log('Calling the function again to get more results if necessary')
        } else {
            // But, checkName is still running because of setTimeout
            // so results doesn't yet have everything we need
            showAll(results)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this is going to send me on the right track.